# How can I stop two hover effects executing at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to generate a tooltip box. When a user hovers over a specified span the box toggles. The propblem is I have 20 or 30 of these on the page, so if a user runs their mouse down the list I get all 30 appearing and dissapearing in sequence. Is there any way I can stop the effect running if there's another tooltip either currently visible or in the process of being animated?

```
    $('td.aO .tTCont').hover( function(){
    $(this).siblings('div.toolTip').delay(100).fadeToggle('200');})
```

Comment: Thinking about it, can I do a callback on the 'onMouseOut' part of the hover function to hide all tooltips? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the current animation with `.stop()` and remove all queued/pending animations with `.clearQueue()`.

Calling (one of) them for the respective selector before you que another animation will do the trick.

You will probably have to play around with them to find a configuration that looks alright. :)

Comment: So would it require something like this:
`$('td.aO .tTCont').hover( function(){`
`$('td.aO .tTCont').stop();`
`$(this).siblings('div.toolTip').delay(100).fadeToggle('200');})`

Comment: make sure to also catch the ones that are still in the que as .stop() only removes the currently executing one.

Comment: Thanks,  after a bit of playing around here's what I'm going with:
`$('td.aO .tTCont').hover( 
   function(){
    $(this).siblings('div.toolTip').fadeIn('200');
   },
   function(){
    $('div.toolTip').clearQueue().stop().css('display','none');
   })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('td.aO .tTCont').hover( function(){
    $(this).children('.toolTip').delay(100).fadeToggle('200');})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but that stopped the tooltips appearing altogether...